# Why the Firebase Model is not populating the layout?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a chat App, using `FirebaseDatabase`, but there is a problem retrieving the message,however user is able to push the message.

I have  used a `ListView` and `FirebaseListAdapter`
there is my method `showMsg()`

```
final ListView msgs = findViewById(R.id.lv_msg);
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().limitToLast(50);
FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessages> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessages>().setQuery(query, ChatMessages.class).setLayout(R.layout.list_item).build();


    chatMessageAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessages>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessages model, int position) {


            TextView msgView, timeView;
            CircleImageView profileView;

            msgView = v.findViewById(R.id.msg_view);
            timeView = v.findViewById(R.id.msg_post_time);
            profileView = v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

            msgView.setText(model.getmText());
            timeView.setText(DateFormat.format("DD-MM-YYYY (HH:MM:SS)", model.getmTime()));
            Picasso.get().load(model.getmUser()).into(profileView);

        }
    };
    msgs.setAdapter(chatMessageAdapter);
```

And here is my database 
[image: Database]

Any one knows where am I doing wrong.

**Updated**

ChatMessage.java

```
public class ChatMessages {

private String mText;
private String mUser;

public long getmTime() {
    return mTime;
}

public void setmTime(long mTime) {
    this.mTime = mTime;
}

private long mTime;

public ChatMessages(String mText, String mUser) {
    this.mText = mText;
    this.mUser = mUser;

    this.mTime = new Date().getTime();
}

public ChatMessages() {
}

public String getmText() {
    return mText;
}

public void setmText(String mText) {
    this.mText = mText;
}

public String getmUser() {
    return mUser;
}

public void setmUser(String mUser) {
    this.mUser = mUser;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any parent node above those messages or is only the root?

Comment: could you post your ChatMessages class?

Comment: @AlexMamo only root.

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque why not.